# 404 Error On Category and Tags Pages

Tags: categories, tags, archives, 404-error, blog

Okay So I'm facing a weird problem as i'm receiving 404 errors on blog category and tag pages.
I'm using custom theme which includes:

- tag.php
- category.php
- archive.php
- home.php
- index.php and
- 404.php.

The Blog archive is working fine but when i try to load tag pages or category pages i'm being redirected to 404.php template file.

Also there is one other weird problem which i'm facing if i remove 404.php file from my theme folder the category and tag links are working fine and loads content from archive.php but it shows page not found on page title and error404 class is added inside the body tag of that page.

Here is the list of items that i've tried so far to solve the issue:

1. Refreshed Permalink Structure.
2. Applied Category and Tag Base.
3. Changing the theme to twentyseventeen in which everything was fine
4. All the code in my header and footer.php file follows wordpress theme guidelines.

Please suggest me a solution that might help to solve this as it works fine without 404.php. The Blogs and Categories on website are imported from other website using Wordpress importer.

Question Update: Why Does Wordpress redirects to 404.php even tough files category.php, archive.php and index.php are present inside Wordpress theme folder on category or tag pages ??

Comment: this is something to do with your theme or plugins. It is unlikely that anyone here will be able to just guess what is wrong. You need to actually debug what is going on in your tag/category templates and why redirection (if it is a redirect and not a simple load) happens.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've disabled all plugins as well, also it works if I change the theme or remove 404.pho file. But if I remove 404 file it shows error in wordpress title but shows all related blogs by category or tag. That's why it's weird I cannot understand how to solve it as I need 404.php file in my theme

Comment: so its a problem with your theme, without seeing its code it will be hard to know the cause

Comment: All the code in header and footer is calling basic wordpress functions like wp_head and wp_footer and wp_nav_menu. No extra functions are called. Also as per wp codex it should use category.php template file so can it be some issue in wordpress 4.9 as I've updated wordpress straight after installing wordpress

Comment: You see the 404 template because the requests are resulting in a 404. If 404.php is not present, then it falls back to using index.php template. Are you visiting a tag or category that contains posts? If yes, then you have code somewhere in your theme that is modifying the main query resulting in no posts being returned.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Milo, I'll look each file in my theme closely now to solve this problem as there is definitely some issue with my code or theme structure.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I was having the same issue in a theme I inherited and came across this question in my search for answers.

In my particular case, I found the following PHP code included in the theme's `function.php` file:

```
if( is_category() || is_date() || is_author() ) {
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query->set_404(); //set to 404 not found page
}
```

This code redirects any category, date, or author archive page to a 404 error (which brings up your 404 theme template). You may want to search for something similar in your theme (assuming you haven't already figured this out).

Comment: In my case it wasn't the theme but rather this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-archive-page-remove installed by someone. Your answer really helped tough to hunt down the issue

Answer (score 1):

please set permalinks

[image]

then after check in category  and tag url

Comment: Hi Dharmishtha, please read the question again I've tried that already

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. However, I added the following to functions.php file (courtesy: wpbeginner.com) to view my custom post types in categories. WordPress does not display any custom post types in categories until we add the following filter.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if( is_category() ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'post', 'your_post_type_name'); // don't forget nav_menu_item to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to your WordPress back-end with this path Settings > Permalinks. Ensure that the base of the category is "category" and the tag is the base "tag" (unless you have some very strange special settings) and just press the "Save Changes" button even if nothing has changed, clicking on the button may cause your category and tag pages to work again.

Don’t forget to clean your WordPress cache for testing.

Comment: Hi vishal please read the question again I've tried that already.

Comment: Can you please share your website so I can check it.

Comment: macrisondev.com.au

Comment: I did check in console and found one error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"
Can you please closed the canvas mark correctly.

Comment: Yes I noticed that as well but the canvas partial was just called in file frontpage.php we are not calling it anywhere else on the website. Also the whole HTML Dom itself is not loading instead it is redirected to 404.php page

Comment: Can you please email me wp-admin credentials?

Comment: Sorry buddy can't do that I can show you the code. Let me know what you want to see